# objective-c- selecting items from a database based on a slider value?

Tags: sql, objective-c

I am trying to make a basic app that first brings you to a view controller with a slier, at the moment no matter what the slider value is it selects all from the database but I want the slider value to select all where the price is like the slider value.

I added this line to my code:

```
  NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from carPrices where price =    %f", slider.value];
```

but it does not work, I get the error:

```
implicit conversion of an objective c pointer to 'const char*' is disallowed with ARC
```

I previously had the line saying `const char *sql` instead,

Please if anybody knows what I could be doing wrong could they please give me some advice.

**EDIT**
Ok so I managed to fix the error by adding this line:

```
NSString *SQLSTMNT = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from carPrices where price = %f", slider.value];   

const char  * sql =[SQLSTMNT UTF8String];
```

but as the prices are very specific is there any way to get it to select prices like the one you chose?

Thanks,
MB.

Comment: Show the line of code that actually causes the error.

Comment: BTW - getting a floating point slider value that exactly equals price values in the database is going to be difficult.

Comment: that's a very good point, I added a line to it, now there are no errors but it still doesn't work- I will post the line in the original post if that is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float values are [hard to work with](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/02/22/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

You cannot reliably check if two values are the same, so `where price = %f` is going to fail.

Instead, you need to do check a range of values:

```
CGFloat min = slider.value - 0.1;
CGFloat max = slider.value + 0.1;
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from carPrices where price > %f and price < %f", min, max];
```